# Remote-connect to Elastic Node via Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Trying to connect to a single Elastic node via Python, but I keep getting errors, mostly related to certificate issues. I have Elastic installed on an Ubuntu server and then try to connect to it from a Windows 10 machine.

Connecting to it via the browser from the Windows machine is no problem. I get the expected output:
[image]

The problem is when I have to connect using Python. I've tried every example in the tutorial page, but none worked. Here's my latest attempt:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from ssl import create_default_context

es_username = 'elastic'
es_password = 'xuVmOMJqLGbLskP3PTpT'
es_host = '10.20.20.131'
es_port = 9200
cafile = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON\certificate.crt'


context = create_default_context(cafile=cafile)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://10.20.20.131'],
    basic_auth=(es_username, es_password),
    scheme="https",
    verify_certs=False,
    port=9200,
    ssl_context=context,
)

print(es.info())
```

I've copied the certificate from the ubuntu server to the Windows machine, but still it refuses to validate it.
[image]

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to open `C:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON` path from the windows explore ? please checkthat path is correct. Also, You are setting `verify_certs` to `False` then why you are passing ssl certificate ?

Comment: Hey @SagarPatel, I did try setting verify_certs to False as well, and it won't work either. Also, despite the fact the path to the crt file is correct, the browser won't open it. I created a test txt file in the same location, and voila, the browser reads it. I also tried using the OpenSSL module to open the crt file, and NOTHNG. Python refuses to read it and gives the same "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. This is bizarre to say the least.